# Action of a connected algebraic group on a multiplicative algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-groups

I'm currently learning algebraic groups with the help of the book of Milne. He makes the following claim :

"every action (by group automorphisms) of a connected algebraic group on a multiplicative group is trivial"

and the proof essentially boils down to the fact that there can be no non-trivial morphism $G\to \mathrm{Aut}(\mu_n)\subseteq \mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ if $G$ is connected.

But I don't understand what allows us to assume that the above morphism is continuous for the discrete topology on the right.

In particular, in characteristic $p$ $\mu_p$ is both connected and multiplicative, and it acts non-trivially on itself [EDIT : not by group automorphisms, so it is a bad example].

So, is an hypothesis missing (like $G$ being smooth) ?

Here are the definitions used :

- an algebraic group is a group scheme of finite type over a field
- a multiplicative group is a group which becomes diagonalizable (ie, a subgroup of some $\mathbb{G}_m^k$) over a field extension
- $\mu_n = \mathrm{spec}\ k[T,T^{-1}]/(T^n-1)$

Thank you for reading me!

Comment: hm the action must be by group automorphisms, so no, but then I realize my example with $\mu_p$ does not work

Comment: What hypothesis prevents $\mu_2$ acting by automorphism on $\mu_3$ ?